# In what circumstances does TextToSpeech.isSpeaking() return true?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) says "Checks whether the TTS engine is busy speaking."

But I just implemented a call to `isSpeaking()` in an `onUtteranceCompletedListener`, where I have at least 10 pending utterances and in **none** of them did I received `true`.

Assuming that `isSpeaking()` actually works as documented, I must conclude that I am calling it incorrectly.

What are the points in which calling TextToSpeech.isSpeaking() returns a valid result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself, thanks to coming across this question (also unanswered):

[Problem with isSpeaking() when using Text-to-Speech on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401805)

The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/tts/TtsService.java#1310) of the TtsService class shows:

```
public boolean isSpeaking() {
  return (mSelf.mIsSpeaking && (mSpeechQueue.size() < 1));
}
```

Which means the TTS engine not only must be speaking but its utterances queue size must be greater than 0.